# Unable to get Mathjax extension to work in Mediawiki

Tags: installation, mediawiki, mathjax

I am trying to install Mathjax on a mediawiki installation. From the [official page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MathJax) for the extension, I followed all the steps.

1. Downloaded the [latest zip distribution](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/), uploaded and extracted it to `/home/user/public_html/wiki/` (the directory where the wiki installation lies)
2. Checked that it works by going to:

   > http://www.mysitename.com/wiki/mathjax/test/sample.html

   Here I see nicely rendered math.
3. Placed `MathJax.php` and `mwMathJaxConfig.js` in the folder:

   ```
   public_html/wiki/extensions/MathJax
   ```
4. Appended the `LocalSettings.php` as instructed by adding the following code:

   ```
   require_once("/home/user/public_html/wiki/extensions/MathJax/MathJax.php");
   $wgMathJaxJS = array("/mathjax/MathJax.js" => "/home/user/public_html/wiki/extensions/MathJax/mwMathJaxConfig.js");
   ```

I have tediously checked that the directory paths are all right and removed any errors. I do not get any errors anymore, but the MathJax just won't render. How do I get mathjax to work on my wiki?

Answer (score 2):

You were probably using an incompatible version for the MW installation you have. Probably too late to answer, but the extension has been updated to work with MW1.18.